# Можно ли создать класс-обертку для асинхронизации методов?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Допустим у нас есть класс внутри которого много синхронных методов:

```
public class A
{
    public int Return5() => 5;

    public string ReturnString() => "string";
}
```

Можно ли создать класс обертку для асинхронизации синхронных методов? Тоесть чтобы на каждый синхронный метод создавался такой же только с возвращаемым типом `Task<>` и вконце названия метода добавлялось окончание Async.  Допустим чтобы это выглядело так:

```
var asyncA = new AsyncClass<A>;

var result = await asyncA.ReturnStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Технически можно, но это обычно не нужно.

Если узкое место у метода — потребление процессора, лучше выставить синхронный интерфейс. Тогда клиенты могут легко запустить задание асинхронно сами:

```
var five = await Task.Run(() => a.Return5());
```

А могут и не запускать асинхронно, если методу это не нужно.

То есть в этом случае просто выставляйте синхронный метод, клиенты сами могут легко превратить его в асинхронный.

---

А вот если же метод не занимает поток для своего выполнения (например, он грузит что-нибудь из интернета, пользуясь `async`-функциями), тогда нужно выставлять только асинхронный метод. Соответственно вы не сможете выставлять *синхронный* метод, разве что искусственно создать его через `Task.Wait()` (что снова-таки не нужно, ведь клиент при желании может сделать это сам).

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме от одного из ключевых разработчиков асинхронных фич C#: [*Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

---

Как технически сделать асинхронную обёртку? Например, через `Task.Run`:

```
public class AsyncA
{
    private A a = new A();
    public Task<int> Return5Async() => Task.Run(() => a.Return5());
    // и т. д.
}
```

Comment: В общем идея понятна, но мне в учебных целях интересно, как такой эффект можно было б добиться.

Comment: @Lightness: Добавил в ответ. Обёртку придётся писать для каждого класса отдельно (а как можно создать неизвестное заранее число методов?)

Comment: А я надеялся что какие-то варианты есть, теперь буду знать что нету. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!

Comment: ну, всегда можно использовать шаблоны, т4 там всякие. Парсинг файлов -> поиск типовых или помеченных аттрибутом -> генерация оберток. Не забываем помечать классы как partial, чтобы методы были легко и удобно доступны из самого класса.

Comment: @Monk: Ну как бы да, кодогенерация заруливает всё.

Comment: Прямая ссылка на статью: [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Спасибо, внёс ссылку в ответ