# Синхронный метод через асинхронный

Tags: c#, .net

Многие API предоставляют как синхронные, так и асинхронные методы.

Собственно, вопрос, допустимо ли делать синхронный код через асинхронный метод?

Ведь по сути в 99% логика не должна менять=> в синхронном методе вызываем асинхронную версию и ждем результата.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли создать класс-обертку для асинхронизации методов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539786/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @Grundy почему дубликат, тут вроде автор в обратную сторону хочет, асинхронный -> синхронный

Comment: @tym32167, там в ответе про обе стороны

Comment: @Grundy, может быть, однако, если там появятся еще ответы, то тот, кто перейдет с этого вопроса на тот, будет ломать голову, "а где собственно ответ который мне нужен?" так как вопрос сам себе отличается формулировкой.

Comment: Вот этот больше подходит: [Синхронный и асинхронный методы и дублирование кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549500/186999)

Comment: @Grundy похоже, однако, мне больше рекомендация вот эта понравилась https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261169/async-and-sync-versions-of-method .

Answer (score 2):

Это анти-паттерн. Если вы делаете библиотеку, синхронные методы должны быть строго синхронными, а асинхронные должны быть строго асинхронными.

Если разработчик вызывает синхронный метод, он ожидает, что выполнение не будет занимать потоки в тред-пуле (если суть метода не отображает явной необходимости такого поведения). Если вы сделали синхронный враппер, внутренние таски могут занимать потоки в тред пуле, и пользователь библиотеки может очень долго ловить ошибку. Кроме этого во время отладки намного удобней видеть синхронный call stack, нежели асинхронный.

Еще одна проблема. Например ваш класс/метод принимает как аргумент любую реализацию `Stream`, и разработчик ожидает, что синхронная версия метода будет вызывать синхронные методы на экземпляре `Stream`: `Read/Write/Flush`, а асинхронная будет работать с `ReadAsync/WriteAsync/FlushAsync`. Это логичное поведение, и не всегда пользователям библиотеки будут нужны дополнительные расходы на создания объектов `Task`, если они пользуются только `MemoryStream`.

При таком подходе будет дублироваться код, но с этим ничего не сделать.

Подробнее об этом: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/
В статье так же отмечено, что изначально метод `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` работал через асинхронные методы, но потом это исправили, так как создавались некоторые проблемы.

Схожий вопрос на англоязычным stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261169/async-and-sync-versions-of-method

Пример оттуда же для уменьшения дублирования кода:

```
private static async Task DownloadToCacheAsync(bool sync)
{
  ...do some analysis to get download locations...
  using (var wc = new WebClient())
  {
    if (sync)
      wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(content.Url), targetPath);
    else
      await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(content.Url), targetPath);
  }
  ...do other stuff...
}
public static Task DownloadToCacheAsync() => DownloadToTaskAsync(sync: false);
public static void DownloadToCache() => DownloadToTaskAsync(sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Скопипасть в свой ответ пример из enSO.

Comment: Приведенный пример кода - тот самый случай, когда нужен класс ValueTask...

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен, для асинхронного метода можно было бы на выходе конвертировать ValueTask в Task, что бы не создавать неудобства пользователю. Жаль он только в Core

Comment: @Zergatul почему только в Core? Пакет `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` имеет реализацию для netstandard 1.0...

Comment: @PavelMayorov спс, буду знать