# Как правильно прокидывать асинхронный запрос наверх?

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl

Есть апи обращения к хранилищу, выглядит примерно так:

```
var storage = await Storages.GetLatest(id);
```

У него мне нужны файлы - `storage.Files.Where(...)`

Собственно, как логичнее оформлять апи вида получить файлы по id хранилища и фильтру файлов?

```
Task<IEnumerable<IFile>> GetFilesAsync(storateId, filter)
```

или

```
IEnumerable<IFile> GetFiles(storageId, filter)
```

Я не понимаю, будет ли тут польза от асинхронного запроса хранилища, если модельку файлов я могу получить только от хранилища, которое ещё надо дождаться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если внутри вы используете асинхронные методы, то делайте метод API [тоже асинхронным](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/), не прячьте асинхронный код за синхронным (т.н. sync over async). Т.о.:

- вы позволите клиенту получить выгоду от асинхронности
- клиент возможно избежит [дедлока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514529/106)
- если клиенту понадобится синхронная реализация, он сам ее сделает исходя из своих требований

P.S. По поводу обратной ситуации, async over sync, был дан ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498418/106).

**UPD**

sync over async мы уже тоже [обсуждали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539786/).

Comment: Я немного не ферштейн. Когда `storage.Files` у меня типа `IEnumerable<IFile>`, будет ли польза вот от такой обертки (http://pastebin.com/tMYCwb5t), условно говоря?

Comment: @Monk да, будет. Вы же сам `storage` получаете асинхронно.

Comment: Забыл записать в вопросе - надо ли каждую таску обвешивать `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, учитывая, что я пока пишу либу, которая потом будет использоваться где то в интерфейсе?

Comment: @Monk да, желательно. Иначе если этот код будет вызываться из UI, то практически весь код методов по цепочке вызова будет выполняться в UI-потоке. `.ConfigureAwait(false)` говорит о том, что контекст захватываться не будет и что *продолжение* метода будет выполнено в дефолтном контексте (читай, в пуле потоков). Соответственно если в продолжении нет никакой работы с компонентами, требующими конкретный поток (а в библиотечном коде такого по идее не должно быть), то нужно указывать `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @Monk Можете так делать - но помните, что это не единственный и не самый лучший способ оптимизации и борьбы с дедлоками (хотя и самый простой). Подробности - по той ссылке, [которую вам уже приводили](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514529/106).